# How to assign data from one table to another in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am looking for a way to assign the prices from a blue table `E1:H3` to the column `C`. Until now I had to check the prices in the blue table and assign them manually dependent on the country and size. I hope there should be a formula or VBA-code, which would more or less automate it.

[image]

Comment: Can you have a try on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to transpose your data. Try below `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination.

```
=INDEX($F$2:$H$3,MATCH(B2,$E$2:$E$3,0),MATCH(A2,$F$1:$H$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: If found it working then please consider accepting it. Tick mark it so that other user can understand problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In column C2 you would type in =SUM(F3) and press enter. Then any time you change the price in Column F3 C2 will change as well. Here is a tutorial on how to use formulas in excel to do various arithmetic: https://www.excel-easy.com/introduction/formulas-functions.html

Comment: Sorry, it does not solve my problem. Once again: We take Africa as an example. It can be a big company (then it should be invoiced in accordance with the blue table 1.500) or a small company (then it should be invoiced 900 as in `F2`. The same with other countries. Dependent on the country (column `A` and the size of the company (column `B`), the column `C` should take over the price from the blue table.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to do it!
First of all, I have transposed my "blue table" - the auxiliary one.
Here is the screenshot

[image]

In the column `C` I have entered a formula:

`{=VLOOKUP(A2&B2,CHOOSE({1.2},$E$2:$E$7&$F$2:$F$7,$G$2:$G$7),2,0)}`

Now it works!